# xsim: How to calculate points of the sections

Tags: calculations, xsim

Is there a simple way to calculate the points a section includes?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise},
exercise/within = section
}

\begin{document}
\section{First  section \\ {\small You can reach ?? points in this section}}

\begin{exercise}[points=3.5]
An exercise in section 1
\end{exercise}



\section{Second  section \\ {\small You can reach ?? points in this section}}
\begin{exercise}[points=1]
An exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=2]
Another exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}

\section{Total \\ {You can reach \printtotalpoints\,  in this letter.}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added a non-expl3 answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the exercises, compare to the current section value and sum the points:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cis_section_points:
  {
    \fp_zero:N \l_tmpa_fp
    \xsim_foreach_exercise_id_type:nn {used}
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT
          { \xsim_get_property:nnn {##1} {##2} {section-value}+0 } = { \value {section} }
          { \fp_add:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {##5} }
      }
    \xsim_print_goal:nnn
      { \fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp }
      { \, \XSIMtranslate {point} }
      { \, \XSIMtranslate {points} }  
  }
```

The macros used above are not documented directly. Their corresponding interface commands are, though.

- `\xsim_foreach_exercise_id_type:nn {used} {..}` is the same as `\ForEachUsedExerciseByID{..}`,
- `\xsim_get_property:nnn {..} {..} {..}` is the same as `\ExercisePropertyGet{..}{..}{..}`, and
- `\xsim_print_goal:nnn {..} {..} {..}` is the same as `\ExerciseGoalValuePrint{..}{..}{..}`

This also means if you are not comfortable with expl3 you can just as well use the documented commands, for example together with `etoolbox`'s tools:

```
\newrobustcmd*\sectionpoints{%
  \def\thissectionpoints{0}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByID{%
    \ifnumcomp
      {\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}+0}={\value{section}}
      {\edef\thissectionpoints{\thissectionpoints+##5}}
      {}%
    }%
  \ExerciseGoalValuePrint
    {\thissectionpoints}
    {\,\XSIMtranslate{point}}
    {\,\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
}
```

[image]

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise},
  exercise/within = section
}

\newrobustcmd*\sectionpoints{%
  \def\thissectionpoints{0}%
  \ForEachUsedExerciseByID{%
    \ifnumcomp
      {\ExercisePropertyGet{##1}{##2}{section-value}+0}={\value{section}}
      {\edef\thissectionpoints{\thissectionpoints+##5}}
      {}%
    }%
  \ExerciseGoalValuePrint
    {\thissectionpoints}
    {\,\XSIMtranslate{point}}
    {\,\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
You can reach \sectionpoints\ in this section

\begin{exercise}[points=3.5]
  An exercise in section 1
\end{exercise}

\section{Second section}
You can reach \sectionpoints\ in this section

\begin{exercise}[points=1]
  An exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=2]
  Another exercise in section 2
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```